# How to add "continued" in repeated <thead> tags when printing an HTML page?

Tags: html, printing-web-page

I have a basic `<table>` with `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.
When printing the HTML document, `<thead>` elements are repeated on each printed page automatically. How can I add custom text, like (continued) to these repeated headings?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) at-rule in combination with the [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element to specify content before your `<thead>` elements.

Add this CSS:

```
@media print {
    thead::before { 
        content: "(continued)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it adds (continued) in every thead, including the first page. It looks weird. I tried to combine your example with @page :first, but it didn't work out. If I already have counter(page), can I use a rule like "if counter(page)!=1 content: smth" ?

Comment: Indeed my title was not entirely correct - I'd like to have "continued" only on those theads that have been automatically repeated by the browser